# Travis-CI: Where do I find the path to the file I downloaded, and find out "where I am"?

Tags: travis-ci

I would like to download data into the travis environment via a public URL:

```
before_install:
- curl -OL http://publicwebsite.org/data/subdirectory2
```

My problem is that I don't know whether the data downloaded successfully.

My question is, how do I now find this data? I have assumed that it would be found at `/home/travis/build/subdirectory2`, but this isn't true.

Commands such as `pwd` and `ls` do not show me the files downloaded in the build, or where I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$PWD` is `$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR` when the execution gets to `before_install`. https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Default-Environment-Variables

If you are unsure of where it is, though, you can pass `-o /path/to/file` to `curl`.

Comment: Is there a way to see it's there? That the file downloaded correctly and is the name I think it is? (I"m basically asking for an 'ls' equivalent)

Comment: If you pass `-f` (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-f) to `curl`, `curl` will exit with nonzero status if the HTTP call does not return a success (2xx), so the build log will indicate the result.

Comment: That's a good point. Question: is there some way to echo where I am? `echo $PWD` doesn't appear to work

Comment: It should work. Do you have a build log URL to show that it's not?

Comment: I think I've found my error. Yes, this appears to work. I appreciate the help!